# How to find the number of items in a DynamicNodeList?

Tags: c#, razor, umbraco

Is there any property or function for DynamicNodeList which returns the number of list items.

This is my code:

```
var root = Model.NodeById(id);
var nodes = root.Descendants("ChartItem");

if (nodes.GetLength() > 0)
{
   s = s + "<ul>";
}
```

But *GetLength* is not a valid function. what should I do?

Comment: Don't you have nodes.Count() available?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a built in extension method for IEnumerable types called Count(), it does just that, it counts the items :)

See code below:

```
var root = Model.NodeById(id);
var nodes = root.Descendants("ChartItem");

if (nodes.Count() > 0)
{
    s = s + "<ul>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
var root = Model.NodeById(id);
var nodes = root.Descendants("ChartItem");

int nodesCount = 0;
foreach (var node in nodes)
{
    nodesCount += 1;
}

if (nodesCount > 0)
{
    s = s + "<ul>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking here

http://umbraco.com/follow-us/blog-archive/2011/12/22/umbraco-5-rc1-is-out-today.aspx

I would try (not sure if the null check is required, or if Descendants() returns at least an empty list)

```
nodes != null && nodes.Count() >0
```

or

```
nodes != null && nodes.Any()
```